# Add button for product

Tags: magento-1.9, multiple-add-to-cart

Can you help me on small project in MEDISON ISLAND go to on page go to on a "SALE" on drop down, click on "MEN"[image: "]. Here in below the product image how I can placed "add to cart button, and when click on  button, the product  should be add into cart.
Please help me step by step, and also suggest me for free book to understand or download. I am entry level in magento.

Answer (score 3):

It is configurable type of product. So on product listing page add to cart button is not showing. It will go that product details page then there is available add to cart button and add to cart this product you need to select product options like size, color.

Comment: it's work for me, great job @Banvari

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't work. Because it is a configurable product. What do you expect to be added to the cart? Which color and which size?

If it is possible to add the product without any questions, the demo shop adds an "add to cart button", like in Jewelry

You can use the following method:
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-add-to-cart-url-of-any-product/

```
$_productId = '166';
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
$_url = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
```

With the `$_url` you can build a button.

Comment: actually i want to learn how i can place an"add to cart button " below product image like  other product  aad to cart button.

Comment: Added a way to add a button. If you have more questions, please be more precise, what you want to achieve, what you try and what doesn't work as expected